# How get PDU from SMS

Tags: java, android

Just wondering whether is it possible to recreate PDU from SMS and how?
I have looked at

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
Object[] aPDUArray = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");

// Here it represent as a byte array, how can i convert it to String ?

}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok i Just found the answer, posted it [here](http://androidbridge.blogspot.com/2011/06/how-get-pdus-from-sms-in-android.html).